# Asp.net Mvc Route not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following route on my mvc 5 project. When I  try to access to the action by url, it throws an 404 error page. What am I doing wrong?

RouteConfig.cs

```
  .... 
routes.MapRoute
       (
              name: "EventMoneyMovements2",
              url: "eventos/{eventID}/movimientos",
              defaults: new { controller = "EventMoneyMovements", action = "ListByEvent", eventID = UrlParameter.Optional }

       );
```

Controller

```
public class EventMoneyMovementsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /EventMoneyMovements/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ListByEvent(int? eventID)
        {

            return View();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the _exact_ url you are trying to goto...

Comment: You're going to need to post your whole RouteConfig. Order matters. If the default route is at the top with {controller}/{action}/{id} it will always be the one that's routed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you are registering the routes matters. You should always **register your specific routes before the generic default route**.

Assuming you register your specific route before your generic like below.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
   routes.MapRoute
   (
          name: "EventMoneyMovements2",
          url: "eventos/{eventID}/movimientos",
          defaults: new { controller = "EventMoneyMovements", action = "ListByEvent",
                                                         eventID = UrlParameter.Optional }

   );
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

With this definition you can access the `ListByEvent` action method with the request url

`yourSiteName/eventos/101/movimientos`  or `yourSitename/EventMoneyMovements/ListByEvent?eventID=101` where `101` is any int value

Answer (score 1):

You must define your custom route before default MVC route because all routes defined in route config maintained in a route table in same order as we define in route config.

For more information refer below url:

> http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs